# Test-cmdlts for Exchange - "Could not establish trust - SSL"

Tags: ssl, exchange-2007

I installed intermediate certs and my main cert (Godaddy) But I keep getting the "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel" when I run cmdlts like Test-WebServicesConnectiviy

I am able to connect to OWA and use as normal though w/SSL...

Should the main SSL be copied to the Trusted Root CA folder?

Answer (score 1):

Run this powershell command `Get-ExchangeCertificate |fl` and look for the Status near the bottom, does it say Valid?

EDIT: Also, did you use Exchange to import the certificate, or did you do it manually?

Comment: Yes. There are three listed. Godaddy is vaild and active for POP SMTP IIS and IMAP

Comment: Second one just says for my local domain, and only service is SMTP. Third one is for "WMsrv-EMAIL" with no services. But all say valid.

Comment: ...may be unrelated, but using OWA, mail can send and not receive...